# UnknownHostException in Java client-server application

Tags: java, client-server

I am designing a Java application that shares files but while trying to activate the methode recieve file and send file i am getting a exception knowing that the user enters the name of the file and the server gets it and gets the file and send it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: Hasan.txt at 
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:177) at 
java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366) at 
java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529) at 
java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478) at 
java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375) at 
java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189) at 
p2pfilesharingproject.ClientP2P.main(ClientP2P.java:25) Java Result: 1
```

here is my code

Client Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ClientP2P {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentence;
        String modifiedSentence;
        System.out.print("which Port  are you going to listen to ?");

        int Socket = s.nextInt();

        String host = s.next();
        BufferedReader inFromUser =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(host, Socket);

        DataOutputStream outToServer =
                new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        BufferedReader inFromServer =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();  
        RecieveFile(sentence);
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence);


    }

    public static void RecieveFile(String Fname)
    {
        byte[] aByte = new byte[1];
        int bytesRead;

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 111);
            is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Do exception handling
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        if (is != null) {

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream("E:\\"+Fname);
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                bytesRead = is.read(aByte, 0, aByte.length);

                do {
                        baos.write(aByte);
                        bytesRead = is.read(aByte);
                } while (bytesRead != -1);

                bos.write(baos.toByteArray());
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.getStackTrace();
            }
    }


}
}
```

Server Cpde

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ServerP2P {

    public static void listfile() {

 String path = "C:/SAVE"; 

  String files;
  File folder = new File(path);
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

  for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
  {

   if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
   {
   files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
   System.out.println(files);
      }
  }
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String clientSentence;
        String capitalizedSentence;
        System.out.print("Listen on Port Number : ");
        int Socket = s.nextInt();

        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(Socket);
        listfile();
        while (true) {

            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

            BufferedReader inFromClient =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));


            DataOutputStream outToClient =
                    new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            String fn = inFromClient.readLine();
            SendFile(fn);


        }
    }

    public static void SendFile(String FileName) {
        while (true) {
            ServerSocket welcomeSocket = null;
            Socket connectionSocket = null;
            BufferedOutputStream outToClient = null;

            try {
                welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(111);
                connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
                outToClient = new BufferedOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Do exception handling
            }


            if (outToClient != null) {
                File myFile = new File("C:\\" + FileName);

                byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

                FileInputStream fis = null;

                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    // Do exception handling
                }
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

                try {
                    bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                    outToClient.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                    outToClient.flush();
                    outToClient.close();
                    connectionSocket.close();

                    // File sent, exit the main method
                    return;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (i) *i am getting a exception* => what exception? on what line? can you post the stacktrace? (ii) you have many empty catch blocks, which means that exceptions are ignored => that is not going to help you. You should at least print something (`ex.printStackTrace();`) to help you debug the issue.

Comment: Seconding @assylias here: what is the exception?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: Hasan.txt
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:177)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
 at p2pfilesharingproject.ClientP2P.main(ClientP2P.java:25)
Java Result: 1

Comment: @RaymondBouChaaya It is easier if you include all the information in your question - I have added the exception.

Comment: In examples, use constants instead of Scanner. That makes it easier to test your program just as you are.

Comment: program output depends on input, and the input is not being specified.

Answer (score 2):

The server called "Hassan.txt" could not be found. Make sure that you can reach that socket via a network. IP addresses are usually numeric (unless you are using "localhost" or your host is listed on DNS); it looks like you are using the name of a file instead of the host itself.